# Contact Access to user

Tags: sharing, owd, sharing-rule

I want to give contact edit permission(without giving delete permission) to user when the organization-wide default for contacts is Controlled by Parent.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Chandra

Comment: are you facing any issue? isn't it straight forward ?

you can go to the profile and give edit permssion.

Comment: yes already user have view,edit permission in profile,i want to give contact edit access to user which contacts are not owned my him

Answer (score 0):

If OWD is restricting the access, create Permission Set to release access for users.
You can create Permission Set and Enable Edit permission for Contact in this permission set and then you can assign this permission set to the user.

If Roles are set up in your Org then you can use Sharing Rules to give access to records which are not owned by user. Using Sharing Rules, you can extend sharing access to users in public groups, roles, or territories. You can actually share records owned by members of one specific Role/Public Group with members of another Role/public Group.

Comment: Hi Rohit thanks for your reply.Actually user profile have Read,Create,Edit,Delete and View All permission.now he can able to edit his own contact record but i want to provide contact edit permission for records which he is not owned

Comment: Hi @ncmouli, is it because of Role hierarchy in your org that a user is not able to access record? Please check my updated answer and let me know.